# Should I use polling in the following code, If yes then how?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, polling

I tried to ping an API using reactJS, PFA Code below.

The API contained almost 12k+ rows, sometimes it would work( I was able to see data ) and rest it would not.

[Image when fetching was successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzS2S.png)
[Image when the fetching was not successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23np0.png)

So on internet I was able to find that their exist some concept of polling in reactJS, where the API will be pinged after every given interval. But I am not sure how to implement it in my code.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import React, { useEffect, Component } from "react";
import './App.css';
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';

const columns = [
  {
    name: 'Id',
    selector: 'id',
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Name',
    selector: 'name',
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Country',
    selector: 'country',
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'logo',
    selector: 'logo',
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Slogan',
    selector: 'slogan',
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Head_Quaters',
    selector: 'head_quaters',
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Website',
    selector: 'website',
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Established',
    selector: 'established',
    sortable: true,
  },

];

class App extends React.Component {

    // Constructor
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            items: [],
            DataisLoaded: false
        };
    }

    // ComponentDidMount is used to
    // execute the code
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(
  "https://api.instantwebtools.net/v1/airlines") 
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((json) => {
                this.setState({
                    items: json,
                    DataisLoaded: true
                });
            })
    }
  
    render() {
        const { DataisLoaded, items } = this.state;
        if (!DataisLoaded) return <div>
            <h1> Please wait some time.... </h1> </div> ;

        return (
    <div className="App">
      <DataTable
        //title="Employees"
        columns={columns}
        data={items}
        pagination
        highlightOnHover
      />
    </div>
    );
}
}

export default App;
```

I am a beginner just started using react so finding it hard. Can someone help me in order to implement polling?

Comment: Bad idea for a payload that large IMO

Answer (score -1):

If you are worried about bringing all that data at the same time, you can indicate from the backend that they send you a certain amount of records and from the frontend (reactjs) you can manage them with pagination.

Comment: can you? that is guaranteed? do you know that API in particular? how would you request "a certain amount of records" from that API?

Comment: https://developers.giphy.com/docs/api/endpoint#trending   This api is very good if you are learning how to consume apis. You can manage the maximum number of objects to return.

Comment: what does that have to do with the API in the question?

Comment: you should put that in your answer rather than as a comment - still, your answer nothing to do with the question - *ooh look, this API, which isn't the API you're using, can do this* - doesn't address the issue AT ALL

Comment: sorry, I read wrong, I thought you asked me if I knew of another api in particular, to consume it and make use of limits of requested elements

Comment: I'm not even the OP ... so ...